# Replication at reducer level in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Do replication of intermediate data (emitted by Mapper) happens when reducer tries to copy them from temp folder?

Answer (score 3):

No, the data emitted by the mapper would be on the mapper machine's local disk. The reducer copies it over the network. If the mapper node goes down during the copy or before the copy has started a new mapper task would be spawned on some other node.

Comment: ok, so reducer when copying data writes to hdfs or not ? if not, where/

Comment: When the reducer emits data the data is stored in the HDFS and one of the replica nodes would be the reducer node itself(or nearest node to the reducer). This would save some network bandwidth.